# Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{200}$ are independent continuous random variables with common density function. Find the $Var(y_i)$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{200}$ are independent continuous random variables with common density function $f(y) = 1(1-y)$ when $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0$ for any other $y$.

Find $Var(y_i)$

We know that in this case that

$Var(y_i) = Var(\frac{1}{200}\sum_{n=1}^{200}Y_n) = \frac{1}{200^2}Var(\sum_{n=1}^{200}Y_n)=\frac{1}{200^2}(E((\sum_{n=1}^{200}Y_n)^2)-E(\sum_{n=1}^{200}Y_n)^2)$

But im not sure how you would continue from this point. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

$f(y)=1(1-y)\mathbb{1}_{[0;1]}(y)$

is not a nice density. After correcting it calculate $V(Y) = V(Y_i)$ for every $i$

If you are interested in $V(\bar{Y}_{200})$ it is simply $\frac{V(Y)}{200}$